# C# .NET Core 5 with Entity Framework Core 5 project is not returning objects from table after successfully adding them

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, localdb

I am creating a .NET Core app using EF Core Code First. In my seeder code, I first delete any existing test database with `await Context.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();` and then create a new database with the `await Context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();` command, using my localDB database.

My problem is that one of my tables, after being properly seeded, is not properly returning data. I have verified that it is correctly saving the data by visually inspecting the table data in SQL server explorer which showed the data records. I also logged the result of `Context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()` which returned true after adding each object. I also logged `await Context.SaveChangesAsync()` which returns the number of changes made to the database which printed 305 when I ran the command after seeding that particular table/Dbset with data.

When hovering any reference to the Context Dbset in question while in debug mode (nullpointerexception after I attempted to access the data from that table through the Context object), the Results View property shows that it is indeed empty, with the message: "Enumeration yielded no results". This is not the case for any of the other Dbsets I created and seeded, which properly enumerate all of the objects contained on their respective tables under the Results View property.

I can't discern any meaningful difference between the way I set up these tables, so I am at a loss here as to why I can't access this one particular table when the rest of them I can access just fine without error.

I have been racking my brain on this for a few days now. If you have any ideas for me to try or if I need to provide any more information please leave a comment and let me know.

Comment: I really think you are trying to do too much all in one blow. Make your solution as small as possible and grow from there. Also, asking a question as complex as this will not get you an answer because people have to wrap their heads around it too.

Comment: Maybe because `itemTemplate` is null?

Answer (score 0):

I was undoing recent changes to see if I could get it to work again, and when I removed a nullable int property in my object's model `public int? ExpirationDays { get; set; }` and made it a regular integer, it started working normally again. Maybe EF core doesn't like nullable types?